# trying to find median of an even and odd list, function returns same answer for both

Tags: python

I am trying to find the median of an even and odd list. It is a long story but I must find the median in this way (no importing anything).

When I pass in myOddList as the parameter, the median is 3 (correct). Yet when I pass in myEvenList as the parameter, I get 3 again. How do I get myEvenList to work correctly and have an output of 3.5?

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myEvenList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def medianCalculator(myEvenList):
    myOddList.sort()
    myEvenList.sort()
    n = len(myOddList)
    s = len(myEvenList)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        answerOdd = myOddList[int(n/2)]
        return answerOdd
    else:
        one = myEvenList [(s-1) // 2]
        two = myEvenList [(s+1) // 2]
        answerEven = (one + two) / 2
        return answerEven

medianForEvenList = medianCalculator(myEvenList)
print(medianForEvenList)
```

Maybe the issue is that I am not returning answerEven correctly?

Comment: Why do you access both lists inside the medianCalculator? medianCalculator should be side-effect free, and only access its input parameter.

Comment: Personally, I think `medianCalculator` should accept and operate on only one list. You would call the function twice with either list

Answer (score 2):

**Problems:**

- You are accessing `myEvenList` and `myOddList` inside `medianCalculator`, which you shouldn't. `medianCalculator` should be detached from any external variables.
- the `myEvenList` parameter shadows the `myEvenList` global variable
- your decision of whether running the even or odd algorithm depends on `n`, which is computed from `myOddList`, therefore it will always only run one of the two sides.
- don't call `sort()` on a parameter, as it will modify the underlying list. Make a copy first.

**Solutions:**

- Make your `medianCalculator` function side-effect free. That means, it shouldn't access any variables outside of its own function, and only operate on its input parameter.
- call `medianCalculator` multiple times, if you want to get multiple answers. Use different parameters to have it operate on different inputs.

**Code:**

```py
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myEvenList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def medianCalculator(myList):
    myList = myList.copy()
    myList.sort()
    n = len(myList)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        answerOdd = myList[int(n/2)]
        return answerOdd
    else:
        one = myList [(n-1) // 2]
        two = myList [(n+1) // 2]
        answerEven = (one + two) / 2
        return answerEven

medianForEvenList = medianCalculator(myEvenList)
print(medianForEvenList)
medianForOddList = medianCalculator(myOddList)
print(medianForOddList)
```

Comment: btw, `myList = myList[:]` or `myList = sorted(myList)` work too

Comment: Thank you, this makes it a lot easier!

Comment: @OneCricketeer agree. I just thought i'd write it as explicit as possible to not hide the problem in implicit steps.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 3 because you're ignoring `myEvenList`

```
n = len(myOddList)
if n % 2 != 0:  # always true
    answerOdd = myOddList[int(n/2)] 
    return answerOdd  # return 3
```

Don't use both lists in the function and only use the parameter that is given

Comment: Ok, I will change the code accordingly. I figured maybe it was possible to use both lists, but I see now that I can't. Thank you!

Comment: Also, depending on other condititions, you'd want to copy the input list and sort it, rather than having the side-effect of modifying the input parameter after the function returns

Answer (score 0):

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myEvenList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def median(lst):
    
    lst = sorted(lst)
    
    lst_length = len(lst)
    midpoint = lst_length/2
    
    if lst_length % 2 != 0:
        return lst[int(midpoint-0.5)]
    else:
        return (lst[int(midpoint-0.5)] + lst[int(midpoint+0.5)])/2
    
print(median(myOddList))
# 3
print(median(myEvenList))
# 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all u making a def so don't create your list in there , secod u should define a def parameter as u later want to use .

```
def median_cal (my_list) : 

    my_list.sort()
    n = len(my_list)

    if n % 2 != 0 :
        x = int(n/2) 
        answer = my_list[x]
        print (answer)

    else : 
        x = int(n/2) - 1 
        y = int(n/2)  
        answer = my_list[x] + my_list[y]
        print (answer/2)

a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]

median_cal(a)
median_cal(b)
```